# Angular combining parallel and chained requests with $http.then() and $q.all()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I have a rather complicated set of API calls to make and I'm attempting to do it as elegantly and performant as possible. I understand how to use the promise api of the `$http` service to chain requests, and how to use the `$q` service to make requests in parallel. But for this specific API workflow I need to do both.

Here is an example of the high-level API flow:

- `/dog/<dog_id>`

  - `/breed/<breed_id>`

    - `/food/<food_id>`
- `/cat/<cat_id>`
- `/turkey/<turkey_id>`
- `/fish/<fish_id>`

The first tier of requests all have known ids. However the `<breed_id>` required to make the `/breed` call must be parsed from the `/dog` response, and the `<food_id>` required to make the `/food` call must be parsed from the `/breed` response. So `/dog`, `/breed`, and `/food` all need to be chained. However `/cat`, `/turkey`, and `/fish` can be made in parallel with the entire `/dog` chain.

What I've got now (and it is working fine) are two separate sets of requests. How do I improve on this flow? Is there a way to combine the two stacks in a way that results in a single promise execution of `.then()`?

```
var dogId = '472053',
    catId = '840385',
    turkeyId = '240987',
    fishId = '510412';

var myData = {};

var firstSetComplete = false,
    secondSetComplete = false,
    returnData = function() {
        if (firstSetComplete && secondSetComplete) {
            console.log("myData.dog", myData.dog);
            console.log("myData.dog.breed", myData.dog.breed);
            console.log("myData.dog.food", myData.dog.food);
            console.log("myData.cat", myData.cat);
            console.log("myData.turkey", myData.turkey);
            console.log("myData.fish", myData.fish);
        }
    };

// first call set
$http.get('http://example.com/dog/' + dogId)
.then(function(response) {
    myData.dog = response.data;
    return $http.get('http://example.com/breed/' + response.data.breed_id);
})
.then(function(response) {
    myData.dog.breed = response.data;
    return $http.get('http://example.com/food/' + response.data.food_id);
})
.then(function(response) {
    myData.dog.food = response.data;

    firstSetComplete = true;
    returnData();
});

// second call set
$q.all([
    $http.get('http://example.com/cat/' + catId),
    $http.get('http://example.com/turkey/' + turkeyId),
    $http.get('http://example.com/fish/' + fishId)
])
.then(function(responses) {
    myData.cat = responses[0].data;
    myData.turkey = responses[1].data;
    myData.fish = responses[2].data;

    secondSetComplete = true;
    returnData();
});
```

Comment: could assign variable to very first request, and include that variable in `$q.all()` array

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can pass in the first chain like so:

```
$q.all([
    $http.get('http://example.com/cat/' + catId),
    $http.get('http://example.com/turkey/' + turkeyId),
    $http.get('http://example.com/fish/' + fishId),
    $http.get('http://example.com/dog/' + dogId)
    .then(function(response) {
         myData.dog = response.data;
         return $http.get('http://example.com/breed/' + response.data.breed_id);
     })
     .then(function(response) {
         myData.dog.breed = response.data;
         return $http.get('http://example.com/food/' + response.data.food_id);
     })
     .then(function(response) {
         myData.dog.food = response.data;
         return myData;
     })
])
.then(function(responses) {
    myData.cat = responses[0].data;
    myData.turkey = responses[1].data;
    myData.fish = responses[2].data;

    secondSetComplete = true;
    returnData();
});
```

That big chain of promises for dogs ends up returning a single promise that is resolved when the last `then` is called and it's resolved with the result from that final function. So there is no reason that you can't nest it in your `$q.all()` call.

Comment: I used this but it ended up calling all the services for each `.then` inside the brackets (maybe my coffeescript was wrong). I fixed it by putting each `.then` after its respective $http call, and the final `.then` worked without modification.

Comment: Will this fire each promise in successively or all in parallel?

Comment: very nice. Thank you!