# Angular 5 combining and chaining parallel calls with forkJoin not working

Tags: angularjs, angular, rxjs, observable, angular5

I am looking for a way to do some action after all controls on a page are loaded. These controls are loaded in parallel by calling http get.

I tried code similar to the one below but it doesn't seem to do the trick. If it worked correctly, the sometext should display 'done'. It doesn't. I am not sure I understand correctly how the forkJoin works. I used to do this kind of chaining in Angular 1.x using promises. Any help in understanding the problem and a solution is appreciated.

The solution I am looking for is similar to this question for Angular 1.x: [Angular combining parallel and chained requests with $http.then() and $q.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252640/angular-combining-parallel-and-chained-requests-with-http-then-and-q-all)

Complete code is at http://plnkr.co/edit/xH6VJo

Source is src/dash.ts

This is Angular 5 and typescript.

```
export class dash implements OnInit {
  sometext = 'Some text ...';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
  };
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  click_me(): void {
    this.sometext = '';
    forkJoin([
      of(this.first_()),
      of(this.second_())
      ]).subscribe(val => {
        this.sometext = 'done...';
      })
  }
  first_(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('data/sampledata.json',this.httpOptions).subscribe(val=> {
    this.sometext = val.items[0].value;
    });
  }
  second_(): void {
    this.http.get<item[]>('data/sampledata.json',this.httpOptions).subscribe(val=> {
    this.sometext = val.items[1].value;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @Igor Would you mind explaining how is this a duplicate of that question?

Comment: The solution for that question is what I used to use in Angular 1.x. But with TypeScript and rxjs, I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: There are also answers specific to angular (angular 2 and higher) that use the rxjs library. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25501002/1260204

Comment: Promises are not supported by Typescript as indicated in that answer. What do you suggest? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main reason is because your `first()` and `second()` doesn't return an `Observable`. `.forkJoin()` can only take in an **array** of `Observables`, fire them in parallel, and then it has to wait for **all** observables to **complete** before it starts to emit the resultant values. The main reason your `complete()` handler never gets executed is because there is no `Observables` in the `.forkJoin()` in the first place, hence none of them can complete, and your `.forkJoin()` will never emit.

Here's what you should do. For `first()` and `second()`, have them return an `observable`. If you want to change the `this.sometext` when both of them executes, use the operator `.do()`:

```
first_(): Observable<any> {
    this.http.get<any>('data/sampledata.json', this.httpOptions)
        .do(val => {
            this.sometext = val.items[0].value;
        });
}

second_(): Observable<any> {
    this.http.get<item[]>('data/sampledata.json', this.httpOptions)
        .do(val => {
            this.sometext = val.items[1].value;
        });
}
```

Now your `click_me()` should be working fine:

```
click_me(): void {
    this.sometext = '';
    forkJoin([
        of(this.first_()),
        of(this.second_())
    ]).subscribe(val => {
        this.sometext = 'done...';
    })
}
```

Note that since `Observable.forkJoin()` fires their requests in parallel, there is **NO GUARANTEE** that your `first()` will be executed before your `second()`.

Comment: Thank you. The order of first and second are not important in this case.